# what dependencies do spark slaves require?

Tags: apache-spark, java

I know how to set up a spark standalone cluster on one machine. (Install,java, install git, install scala, install spark, configure environment variables and PATH, passwordless ssh login-ability).

But what is needed in the slave machines. Obviously JAVA since SPARK prob behaves like hadoop, shipping the jar file to the various slave machines where the RDD lives. But do the slaves need scala and spark as well?

Comment: You don't need Scala, git or even ssh to run standalone Spark cluster. Basically what you need is JRE, Spark binaries, a way to access individual machines (yeah lets include ssh :) to start workers and a network configuration which allows communication between workers and master.

Comment: so it's just java that the slaves need?

Comment: If you ask about standard pre-build binaries and bare minimum then yes. I don't see any reason why you need anything else for the master.